# Difference between と and とは

Tags: usage, particles

Difference between と and とは？

For example in below sentences

> そんなに大きいと思わなかった。

and

> そんなに大きいとは思わなかった。

Comment: +1 because it is a good question but the example sentence are not the best because each can mean two VERY different things.

Comment: そんなに大きいとは思わなかった can mean 1. I didn't expect it would be so big (before I saw it). 2. I didn't think it was that big (when I saw it).

Comment: @Unknown Forgive me but those statements seem equivalent to me. (I am an English native)

Comment: @paullb　Hmm? (1) is like そんなに大きいとは思っていなかったが、実際に見てみると、意外に大きかった。I had not expected it to be so big. It was bigger than I had expected. Contrary to my expectations, it was big. (2) is like 私はそれをそんなに大きいとは思わなかった。むしろ小さいと思った。I saw it and didn't think it was big. Rather, I thought it was quite small. When I saw it, I had an impression that it was not big.

Answer (score 8):

*In this case,* there is very little difference, although the latter strikes me as a bit more common.

I would categorize the は in the latter sentence as a contrastive wa: "(I knew it was big, but) I didn't think it was this big".

Answer (score 0):

I think the は in とは is an emphasis on と